# build pytorch documentation import error

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to build pytorch's documentation. I insatlled sphinx and readthedocs theme. And ran the commands on the pytorch GitHub page for building the documentation. When I run make single html or any other format, they all give me an import error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "source/scripts/build_activation_images.py", line 8, in <module>
import torch.nn.modules.activation
ImportError: No module named torch.nn.modules.activation
make: *** [figures] Error 1
```

I think the script is trying to use python 2 instead of python 3 because I have to type python3 and pip3 to use python 3 and the GitHub page used pip.

But I'm not really sure and I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `virtualenv` installed. You also need `katex`

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get install node-katex
```

Then this worked for me:

```bsh
pytorch-1.7.1/docs$ virtualenv venv --python=python3
pytorch-1.7.1/docs$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) pytorch-1.7.1/docs$ pip install -r requirements.txt 
(venv) pytorch-1.7.1/docs$ pip install torch==1.7.1
(venv) pytorch-1.7.1/docs$ make singlehtml
```

(Some errors were reported but it produced a single html output)